# Error When Create PHP Files on Server with PHP Script

Tags: php

I am trying to make a PHP Script for Creating PHP Files on my Server but I'm got this Error :

**`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/judiesst/public_html/77/create.php on line 3`**

and here is php scipt for create php files on server

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.php';
$somecontent = "<?php $jdst_xx = "HELLO"; ?>\n";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

/// and the other problem was 
when i'm run this script (create normal text files [not a php script]) it works but next time when i'm run this script again the content in output files was merge with a previous content , so i want the script to rewrite all content in output files ,not merge with a previous content but i'dont know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhenEver you have double Quotes inside double Quotes, you either need to escape them or replace them with single Quotes.

So you could use something like this

```
$somecontent = "<?php $jdst_xx = \"HELLO\"; ?>\n";
```

or

```
$somecontent = "<?php $jdst_xx = 'HELLO'; ?>\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$somecontent = "<?php $jdst_xx = "HELLO"; ?>\n";
```

To

```
$somecontent = "<?php $jdst_xx = 'HELLO'; ?>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks and How to Make this script rewrite content in Output Files , Now it's only merge a new content with a previous content (in the same files)